# How to receive Gmail notifications with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, gmail

I know this seems like a basic question, but I can't find a clear answer to it. I want to develop an Android app with Xamarin to receive push notifications (new messages) from a Gmail account. I know the native Gmail app already does this, but for a few reasons I need to implement this funcionality myself. I searched about GCM, FCM, but I haven't found a single guide or example on how to do this. Please help!

Comment: If you are going to use FCM in your app then you can send push notifcations from your developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the challenging bit here is the Gmail part.

For your scenario to work:

- Gmail will need to forward its changes to a server-side application that you control
- This server-side application will need to create a push notification by sending it to GCM/FCM's web services
- From here you will need to implement push notifications normally in a Xamarin.Android app

I don't think you are going to find a prebuilt/off-shelf solution that achieves this.

This is a pretty tall order to implement yourself, but it seems to be quite possible. I will walk through what I would do to make this work:

- Implement an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) to act as a webhook for Gmail. Docs for Gmail [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). I don't know if there is an example for this part.
- Use [Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) to send push notifications. Your webhook will forward notifications to the hub. I have a sample [here](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XamSnap/blob/master/wwwroot/sendmessage/run.csx) of sending from an Azure function.
- Integrate the [Azure Notification Hub SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) into your Xamarin.Android app

Like I said, this is quite a bit of work. I'm not sure if you have Windows Azure or Xamarin experience, but I think this is the easiest path forward for a new project using C#.

I have a book [here](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/xamarin-4x-cross-platform-application-development-third-edition) (make sure you get 3rd edition) that covers push notifications and Azure functions in Xamarin apps. The sample code for the book is on [Github](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/XamSnap) if you want a free resource.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Zappier, it integrates well with OneSignal which sends notification on top of Firebase. setup is easier than you can imagine.

I wanted to achieve a quite similar application to what you wanted to achieve. In my case, I wanted to develop a xamarin app that fetches a specific user's tweet and pop a notification to android client automatically.

- Zappier provided easy integration between twitter and onesignal.
- Onesignal automated the messaging.

Take a look at here for pre provided integrations:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/zapier